# ms Access LEFT JOIN skipping a lot of IDs

Tags: ms-access, query-optimization

I'm developing a C# application that needs to access a large amount of data in an MS Access database.
I have the necessity to optimize a query on a table with 100/120k records.

I need to select top n records skipping some ID's (sometimes there are few ids, other times there are many)

My first query was something like:

```
SELECT TOP [quantity] * FROM [table_name] WHERE Id NOT IN (list_of_id's)
```

but this query is really slow.
So i tried another approach:

```
SELECT TOP [quantity] t1.* FROM [table_name] AS t1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Id FROM [table_name] WHERE Id IN (list_of_id's) AS t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
WHERE t2.Id IS NULL
```

is faster, but still slow (maybe for the IN statement)
Can someone give me some hints o an idea on how can i optimize it?
or maybe it is already optimized and the problem is my approach/in the C# application.

thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: I have never seen TOP N using a field or prompt for input. I am surprised this executes at all. My attempt fails "The SELECT statement incldues a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect".

Comment: the quantity is inserted by the user (could be 1 or 100k) but is an integer, i dont know what u mean.

Comment: What do you mean by "inserted by user"? Inserted how? Does user open query in SQL View and replace "[quantity]" with an actual number? How is the list of ID's input - same way? Or are you building this SQL string in C# - perhaps show code? I presume you tested this query directly in Access query object first?

Comment: Since you have a working method and there is no error to address, question not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: i dont think the question is inappropriate.. i mean, it works but is very slow.. i'm asking if someone can help me optimizing it.. 
Yes, i tested it directly in Access db and i insert the [quantity] and [list_of_id's] from C# code (from here I understood that the slowness is not related to what I call it, but it is the query itself that is slow... That's why I didn't code in C#... it would have only complicated the issue)

Comment: The list of id's is a integer list like (1, 2, 10, 30, 54, 56, 67 .. and more)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the slowness is linked to the "IN" STATEMENT..

this is the solution I arrived at, I don't know if it's right.. but it partially solves my problem:
so.. before executing the query, I create an index for the table

```
CREATE INDEX [index_name] ON [table_name] ([primary_key]);
```

it's still slow, but definitely faster than not having indexing.